# Image Map Area Highlight and Zooming with iScroll 4

Tags: javascript, cordova, iscroll, imagemapster

In my Cordova project, I have a slider with multiple zoomable images (by iScroll) and I would like to use map to highlight some area always. But I have tried many libraries like imagemapster.js, maphilight.js but these libraries prevent images' zooming feature. Is there any library that I can use to highlight area only.

Any help or idea. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got figured it out. For someone like me, here is my solution.

I used [imagemapster.js](http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/default.aspx?what.html) for highlighting map areas. But I applied imagemapster first and then I grab those whole element and then applied [iScroll(version 4)](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4) for zooming. First, i was doing backward, that's why I can't zoom in or out anymore. Cheer!